# Law of Cosines and Heron's Formula in inequalities

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, systems-of-equations, triangles, geometric-inequalities

I had the following question:

> Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are non-zero real numbers, and $x$, $y$, and $z$ satisfy the equations
>   $$
> bx + ay = c, cx + az = b, cy + bz = a.
> $$
>   Prove that $-1 < x, y, z < 1$ if and only if $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 < 2 (a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2)$.

After some thoughts, I factorized the inequality to $(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)>0$, which I believe is related to Heron's Formula of area.

I also rewrote the three equations into $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bcx$, $b^2=a^2+c^2-2acy$ and $c^2=a^2+b^2-2abz$, which I believe is related to the Law of Cosine.

I am guessing that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of triangles and $x$, $y$, $z$ are the cosine value to the angle opposite the sides. However, I wasn't able to do this without assuming the side lengths are positive.

Comment: If the signs of $a, b$ and $c$ are all flipped, the truth-value of your inequality related to Heron's formula remains the same. Moreover, the three equalities remain equalities (LHS=RHS iff -LHS=-RHS). So does it help to assume the side lengths all have the same sign, rather than are all positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following can help.

Since $$0<a^2b^2c^2=ab\cdot ac\cdot bc,$$ we can assume that $$bc>0.$$
Thus, since $-1<x<1$ and by your work $x=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc},$ we obtain:
$$-1<\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}<1,$$ which gives
$$(a+b+c)(b+c-a)>0$$ and $$(a+b-c)(a+c-b)>0$$ and from here
$$(a+b+c)\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)>0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)>0.$$
Also, let $\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)>0,$ $abc\neq0$, $x=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc},$ $y=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$ and $z=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}.$

We need to prove that $$\{x,y,z\}\subset(-1,1).$$

Indeed, changing $a$ on $-a$ does not change the condition $$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)>0$$ and what we need to prove.

Thus, we can assume that $a>0$, $b>0$ and $c>0$ and the rest is smooth.

Comment: Can $a$, $b$, $c$ not be negatives?

Comment: @chnmasta05 I proved that if $\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)>0$ and $a,$ $b$ and $c$ are non-negatives so $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Comment: @chnmasta05 I have found something interesting.  See now.